# Bind to TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, treeview

I'm trying to bind a class with a dictionary to a treeview.  The base class of the objects to bind is ElementT:

```
// Base.cs in Base.dll

public class ElementT {

  protected ElementT mParent;
  private string mKey;
  protected Dictionary<string, ElementT> mMembers;
  //...
  public ElementT(string nodeKey) { mKey = nodeKey; }
  //...
  public ElementT Parent {
    get {return mParent}
    protected set { mParent = value; }
    }
  public string Key => mKey;
  public Dictionary<string, ElementT> Members => mMembers;
  //...
  }

public class NamespaceT : ElementT {

  public NamespaceT(string key) : base(key) {}
}
```

Referenced to this base class is EngineT:

```
  // Engine.cs in Engine.dll (References base.dll)

  public sealed class EngineT {

  private NamespaceT mRoot;

  public EngineT() {

    mRoot = RootNamespaceT.GetInstance(null);
    //...
    }

  public ElementT RootElement => mRoot;
  }

internal class RootNamespaceT : NamespaceT {

  //...
  private RootNamespaceT() : base("Root") { }
  //...
  }
```

In the wpf window class referencing Engine.dll:

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs (references Engine.dll) 

public partial class MainWindow : Window {

private EngineT mEngine;
private ObservableCollection<ElementT> mElementList;

public MainWindow() {

  mEngine = new EngineT();
  mElementList = new ObservableCollection<ElementT>();
  mElementList.Add(mEngine.RootElement);

  InitializeComponent();


  //ElementLibraryTreeView.ItemsSource = elementList; ????

  }
}
```

In the XAML:

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource local:mElementList}}">
      <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Key}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Members}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.Resources>


    </TreeView>
```

My goal is to list the Key (mKey) with members of the dictionary Members (mMembers) as children to n levels.  In addition, I need to be able to alter the tree display based upon the derived class type such as Namespace.  There are many different types that derive from ElementT.  My immediate problem is binding the root instance of ElementT to the treeview in code.  I'd appreciate any help I can get to point me in the right direction.   Thank you.

Comment: what does your " => " stand for?

Comment: That is an expression bodied property, a new feature in C# 6.0.   It's a new syntax for a getter only property.